# what is new! in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently refactoring two very messy methods. I would like to add that the
previous developer has absolutely no clue what he was doing and all the codes
just makes the front end look good.

This is the new method

```
def new
  @sponsorships = Sponsorship.all  
  if current_student.organization and current_student.organization.events and current_student.organization.events.count > 0
    #mixpanel.track('Visited to Create More Events')
  else
    #mixpanel.track('Visited Event Registration Page')
  end
  @sponsorship_application = SponsorshipApplication.new(
    sponsorship_id: session[:sponsorship_id])
  new!
end
```

Can someone tell me what is `new!`? I have heard of `create!`, `create` and
`build` but not `new!`.

If I comment that out, I am getting

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

because the `simple_form` is looking for a `@event` to edit and that doesn't
happen until the create method...

Comment: One assumes it's defined somewhere else in the class as in def new! Not sure how we are meant to tell you anything about it though.

Comment: I do not know what `new!` means, but `!` alone must mean that the method is somehow more dangerous in that it might either change its receiver, or have some other side effects. If this doesn't hold, the developer should not use `!` in the method name.

Comment: or also look in the superclass if any.

Comment: Do a search in your code for `def new!` and see if you find anything.

Comment: does he use the `inherited_resources` gem? if i rememeber correctly, it defines bang methods for all standard crud actions, just aliases to the standard actions, but usually used to override them

Comment: take a look here: https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources#overwriting-actions